# Dropdowns populated from Excel tables not getting selected properly

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-datatable

I have a powerapp with dropdowns that are being populated from Excel tables in a separate sheet from the Excel data. Please see attached images of Excel data and tables in two separate sheets.

[Excel data][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rn9Z4.png
[Excel tables][2]   [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbOnU.png

The dropdowns are getting populated properly but I noticed when I look at a record in Edit mode, close out ad then go back to the main screen and click on New, the dropdowns are displaying the values of the Edit record I just looked at, instead of being defaulted to blank.

Has anyone else encountered this before? Is it even worth it to populate powerapps dropdowns from Excel spreadsheets when that works so much better from a Sharepoint List?

Answer (score 0):

This is very classic case of power-apps Cache. Power-apps cached your data and hence you see drop downs previously selected.

What you can do is, when navigate back to main form after your edit is done, Refresh that main form so that cache will be gone.

There is one classic example of Power-apps and how to reset/refresh from

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/Edit-Form-retains-value-from-cache/td-p/292778

Comment: That didn't work for me, sorry. Is there a resource that explains how to get dropdowns to work on PowerApps forms?

Comment: I made this change to Data -> Default of each dropdown Ex: If(EditForm1.Mode = FormMode.Edit, DataCardValue15.Text, "1")  (where DataCardValuexyz is the associated DataCardvVlue for this dropdown from the previous DetailScreen1 page.)

Comment: Yes, I made the changes I wrote on my last comment and that seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: @Burak you can post it as answer & mark it to help others.